# Can you have powershell install a manually downloaded windows update file? No-network environment

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2016

Is it possible to download Windows updates manualy on one machine and then transfer the update files to a machine with no network access and then have powershell install the updates from those file? I want to have a scripted process to install the update files that are transfered to the machine.

I know it is possible to have powershell download and install updates but this is a closed environment. So the files have to brought in on disk.

To shed some light on the programming side of this, I found this script:

```
$Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'"

$Searcher = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Searcher

$SearchResult = $Searcher.Search($Criteria).Updates
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session

$Downloader = $Session.CreateUpdateDownloader()
$Downloader.Updates = $SearchResult
$Downloader.Download()

$Installer = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Installer
$Installer.Updates = $SearchResult
$Result = $Installer.Install()
If ($Result.rebootRequired) { Restart-Computer }
```

This seems to show that you can 'kick-off' an 'installer' job using powershell, but the installer command is being passed the $SearchResult object. What I want to know is:  Is there a way to pass a file (the file path) directly into the $Installer object? 
I have been searching through the powershell documentaion but haven't found anything.

Comment: This is off-topic at SO and better suited to Superuser - unless there's a programming question. That being said, are you familiar with [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx)?

Comment: I have updated my question. And I am familiar with Microsoft Update Catalog. The environment I am working with is on a closed network. So the updates will have to be downloaded from the catalog and physically brought into the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not a PowerShell solution, but have you already tried [WSUS Offline Update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) ?

Using "WSUS Offline Update", you can update any computer running Microsoft Windows and Office safely, quickly and without an Internet connection.

Comment: I saw it, but had never heard of it before. Ramdom windows 'utilities' are scary! So you're saying it's a legitimate thing? Have you used it before?

Comment: Personally I have used it several times and never gave any problems. it's not really a random tool, it has existed for about a decade a new version is released every month. (IMHO the best WSUS alternative for offline computer)